# Pandas Panel is deprecated,

Tags: python, pandas

This code snippet is from one of my script which works fine in current panda version (0.23) but Panel is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.

```
panel = pd.Panel(dict(df1=dataframe1,df2=dataframe2))
diff_output = diff_panel.apply(report_diff, axis=0)
```

Can someone please help me in translating this which is compatible with the latest version of panda? Its say use .to_xarray or pandas.to_frame()

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#deprecate-panel

Comment: http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/pandas.html#panel-transition

Comment: Thanks. I have seen these. If I use panel it gives warning as "Panel is deprecated and will be removed in a future version" If I use Xarray, I can't use .apply function. I would thankful to you if can translate the code.

Comment: It was news to me when I read the question. From the *Panel to xarray* transition document it looks like you get to choose between a 3-d DataArray or a DataSet with multiple 2-d DataArray's and looking a bit further, DataFrame's can be used as arguments to either. It's going to take a little more reading to figure out which would be better for you but I imagine, simply applying a function could be done for either.  Maybe someone else will chime in.

Comment: I appreciate your reply. People here love to downvote rather than helping.

Comment: ..I have only found an `.apply()` method for the DataSet.  Installing 
 xarray now...

Comment: `dict(df1,df2)` isn't valid.

Comment: This code is just small portion of a script where df1 & df2 are dataframes defined earlier. You can use any dataframes in place of df1 and df2

Comment: Yes but `dict(df1, df2)` produces a TypeError.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import xarray as xr
a = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],'b':[4,5,6],'c':[7,8,9]})
b = pd.DataFrame({'a':[11,12,13],'b':[14,15,16],'c':[17,18,19]})
ds = xr.Dataset({1:a, 2:b})
def f(thing):
    #print(thing)
    return thing.mean()
>>> q = ds.apply(f)
>>> q
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  ()
Data variables:
    1        float64 5.0
    2        float64 15.0
>>> q[1]
<xarray.DataArray 1 ()>
array(5.)
>>> q[1].values
array(5.)
```

Comment: I appreciate your time. I will check this. Thanks